# Django rest framework, can not logout

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am using django restframework with TokenAuthentication. So if I go for example to this api call:

```
http://192.168.1.67:8000/api/categories/
```

Then the user has to login. But when I trigger the logout button. the logout doens't  work. And I see in the terminal. That there are two api calls are triggered when the user triggers the logout button:

```
[18/May/2023 10:42:14] "GET /api-auth/logout/?next=/api/categories/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[18/May/2023 10:42:15] "GET /api/categories/ HTTP/1.1" 200 32866
```

So this is the urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', views.CreateUserView.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('logout/',views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),    
    path('token/', views.CreateTokenView.as_view(), name='token'),
    path('me/', views. ManageUserView.as_view(), name='me'),    
    path('login/', obtain_auth_token, name='login' )
]
```

and settings.py:

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/"


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS':'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
    
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'SWAGGER_SETTINGS' : {
    'LOGIN_URL': 'rest_framework:login',
    'LOGOUT_URL': 'rest_framework:logout'
}    
    
}
```

and views.py:

```
class AnimalViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This API endpoint allows viewing animal descriptions.

    - To view a specific animal, append the url with its [/id](/api/animal/1/).
    - To view all the animals in a category, use [/category/id](/api/categories/1/).
    """
    queryset = Animal.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = AnimalSerializer
    permission_classes = ( IsAuthenticated, )


class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This API endpoint allows for the viewing of animal categories.

    All categories include their direct subcategories and animals.

    - To view a specific category, append the url with its [/id](/api/categories/1/).
    - To get all top-level categories use [/main_groups](/api/categories/main_groups).
    """

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'action') and self.action == 'main_groups':
            return MainGroupSerializer
        return CategorySerializer
    

    queryset = Category.objects.all().order_by('name')
    queryset = CategorySerializer.eager_load(queryset)
    serializer_class = get_serializer_class(super)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
```

Question: how to logout the user when the logout button is triggered in django rest framework?